# Regular Expression for 3 uppercase letter, no more or less

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find a regular expression, using Javascript, that will return true when matching 3 letters in uppercase, but it has to be exactly 3, not more or less

```
Correct:

ASD
WER
ERT

Wrong:

QeW
Q3W
QW
QWER
```

This is my code, but it also matches 4-letter strings

```
var r = /[A-Z]{3}/;
r.test("WEE");      //Should return "true"
r.test("WEER");     //Should return "false"
```

Comment: Try Debuggex, Dbugger! -> http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%5E%5BA-Z%5D%7B3%7D%24&flags=&str=WEER

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to anchor your regex:

```
var r = /^[A-Z]{3}$/;
```

`^` matches the beginning of the string and `$` matches the end of the string. This will force the whole string to match the regex to pass.

Answer (score 2):

you should specify the beginning `^` and the end `$` of the string in your regexp pattern:

```
var r = /^[A-Z]{3}$/;
```